# How Do I Remove Comment Date and/or Comment Date Link

Tags: comment-meta

Found this code in the WP Codex but not sure how to use it to remove the hyperlink and/or date from comments.

```
delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

Comment: Are you talking about changing how it's displayed on your site? Or actually destroying that part of the comment's data?

Comment: removing the date from all comments or removing the link in the date.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your comments date Put this code in your current theme function.php file

```
// Remove comment date
function wpb_remove_comment_date($date, $d, $comment) { 
        return;
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wpb_remove_comment_date', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your theme has its own comment template by going to [yoursite.com]/wp-admin/theme-editor.php (when logged in as an administrator). Then look at the right column and try to find comments.php file. If it's there, it controls the way your comments are displayed, so you can manually delete hyperlinks and dates from it.

If you can't find date printed out in comments.php, go to functions.php and try to find it there (search for functions containing word "comments"). Try to find `get_comment_date()` or `get_comment_time()`.

And before you delete any line of code - always backup the content of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your `style.css` file or in a `custom.css` file.(It will hide the comment metadata).

```
.comment-meta {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain as how it helps OP.

Comment: Changing the Publish date after you relaunch a Post can boost the rankings, increase organic traffic. When Blog content is relaunched, including dates with comments can cause confusion when you re-publish your post, as it will show old dates in the comments.

Modifying the publication date will take the post to the top of your blog page and visitors will take it as recent content.

Content relaunch means, you take an old post, improve and update the content. Old post gets outdated, you need to make your content much better before a content relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind getting rid of the date you can add this to the CSS Inserts.

```
.comment-meta  {display:none;}
.comment-meta a {display:none;}
.comment-meta span a {display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your custom stylesheet:

```
time.woocommerce-review__published-date {
    display: none;
}

span.woocommerce-review__dash {
    display: none;
}
```